# Inserting sumif into all the cells of a column

Tags: vba

I would like to insert IF(A2<>"Sub-task",SUMIF(D:D,D2,I:I),"  ") in Cell J2 using vba.  I then want to copy this formula down to every row in column J until the last row of data in Column D

Answer (score 0):

The following should work.  It assigns the formula you requested to all cells in column J, starting from row 2 and ending at the row containing the last used cell in column D.

```
Sub Test
    With ActiveSheet
        .Range("J2:J" & .Cells(.Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).Row).Formula = _
              "=IF(A2<>""Sub-task"",SUMIF(D:D,D2,I:I),"" "")"
    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score -1):

I'm using Excel 2007 and it was giving me an error for

```
Range("J2").Value = "=" & "IF(A2<>""Sub-task"",SUMIF(D:D,D2,I:I),"""")"
```

My workaround for this was just slapping the formula on the end of an equals sign and that worked for some reason. To count the rows in D, I just made a while loop with "i" to keep track of the rows. However, this will stop the copying right after it hits an empty cell in D, so if you have blank rows you'll have to loop it differently.

```
Sub SumIfSub()
    Dim i As Integer

    Range("J2").Value = "="
    Range("J2").Value = Range("J2").Value & "IF(A2<>""Sub-task"",SUMIF(D:D,D2,I:I),"""")"

    i = 3
    Do While (Range("D" & i).Value <> "")
        Range("J" & i).Value = Range("J2").Value
        i = i + 1
    Loop
End Sub
```